# How to remove a file with unprintable charaters in Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing file with strange characters in filename in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/172121/removing-file-with-strange-characters-in-filename-in-os-x)

I have a folder that has a file who's name is Icons and ends with an additiona unprintable character. I can see the unprintable if I ls with -B option:

```
$ ls -B
$ Icon\015
```

if I use ls -b I get:

```
$ ls -b
$ Icon\r
```

I would like to delete file but I cannot find a way to type the unprintable character. If I do:

```
$ rm Icon\015
```

I get:

```
$ Icon\015: No such file or directory
```

If I do:

```
$ rm Icon\r
```

I get:

```
$ Icon\r: No such file or directory
```

I could just delete the whole folder, but I need a more generic way to do this since such files pop up on many users folders.

Comment: If there are no other files that start with Icon, try
`rm Icon*`.

Alternatively, type 
`rm Icon` and then press the <Tab> key (it would complete the filename, if there is only one file starting with Icon).

Comment: @lupincho: The <Tab> key method does work, I actually get Icon^M this way. But I need something I can write into a shell script to automate the removal of such files. BTW: Typing Icon^M does not work....

Comment: What happens if you try `rm -i Icon*`?, Also, are there other files staring with `Icon` in the same directory, but that you don't want to delete?

Comment: @lupincho: rm -i Icon* will work, howeve it will require operator attention. There could be other files starting with Icon, so I cannot take chance that these otehr files will be erased.

Comment: These files contain a user-specified folder-icon. Why would you want to remove them in the first place? After all it's a users decision to give that folder a customized look. The name contains that character on purpose so that it is not easy to remove.

Comment: Did you try putting the name into single quotes? ```rm 'Icon\r'``` should do the trick.

Comment: Just single quotes will not do. You need the '$' as @Gordon Davisson mentions in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell will automatically transform every CR (`\r`) in a LF (`\n`) and execute the preceding command. However, you can use `echo` to produce a LF character. All of these should work:

```
rm $(echo -e "Icon\r")

rm $(echo -e "Icon\015")

echo -e "Icon\r" | xargs rm

echo -en "Icon\r" | xargs -0 rm
```

The last option should be fairly robust and deal with all possible strange characters.

Comment: The Icon is a file not directory, so your method work, replacing rmdir with rm. This method could work in shell scripts so it does the work for me.The -e option to echo does not appear in the man page, how did you come by it? In any case I will accept the answer - thanks!

Comment: Right, I misread the question's first sentence. `men echo` shows `-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to include non-printing characters in a command line. The simplest (bash-only) option is to use `$` before a single-quoted string, which makes bash do escape substitution within the string. Note that it handles several kinds of escape sequences, so both of these would work:

```
rm $'Icon\r'
rm $'Icon\015'
```

Or, you can type Control-V before Control-M (aka return), which tells the shell "the next character I type should be included literally in the command":

```
rm Icon^V^M
```

(Note that the ^V isn't really part of the command, so it won't echo on the command line).

Comment: The $ method works as well as the echo -e method. It's a good solution - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a one unprintable character you can use '?' as a wildcard for one character. So, abc?def?.zip would mean abc1def2.zip and also abc!def#.zip.